# How to setResources dynamically for FlatItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I want to use FlatFileItemWriter without complex Spring Batch flow. Here my code :

```
@Component
public class MyClass implement InitializingBean {
   ......
   private FlatFileItemWriter<MyObject> writer;

   @Override
   public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
     BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
      extractor.setNames(new String[] { "id", "name"});

      DelimitedLineAggregator<MyObject> agregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<MyObject>();
        lineAgregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor);

      writer = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyObject>()
            .append(true)
            .lineAggregator(agregator).build();
   }

   public void method(List<MyObject> myList) {
      File tmpOutputCsvFile = File.createTempFile("output-", ".csv.tmp");

      writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(tmpOutputCsvFile));
      writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
      writer.write(toCsvRecords(transactionRefunds));
      writer.close();
      
      sendToOtherClass(tmpOutputCsvFile);
   }
}
```

But when I run my test, it's always got error : "A Resource is required" at line "writer = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder() ....."

My question, can we set resource dynamically for my case? any suggestion?

Comment: Which version of Spring Batch do you use? In recent versions, you should only have a warning (which is for another use case, but still), see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/commit/707b1bf98623a850e023aef5f9f3fb320fe06cf5. However, according to your code, this: `File tmpOutputCsvFile = File.createTempFile("output-", ".csv.tmp");
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(tmpOutputCsvFile));` does not depend on the method parameter `myList`, so it could be moved to `afterPropertiesSet`.

Comment: But I want to create a new temporary file every `method` been called. Is it not possible? Btw spring boot 2.1.0 and didn't used specific spring-batch.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve *without* referring to Spring Batch? I believe you are asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. Please check https://xyproblem.info and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.